# Reversed Binary Numbers

Tags: java, binary

I was trying a little puzzle which i found [here](https://www.spotify.com/int/jobs/tech/reversed-binary/)

and I was wondering how come my answer is incorrect, you see the original specification is

> Your task will be to write a program for reversing numbers in binary.
>   For instance, the binary representation of 13 is 1101, and reversing
>   it gives 1011, which corresponds to number 11.

So Here is my code..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseBinary {

    public  String reversedIntToBinary(int val) {
        int value = val;
        StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();

        while (value != 0) {
            int remainder = value % 2;
            value = value / 2;
            bldr.append(remainder);
        }
        return bldr.toString();
    }

    public  int toDecimal(String bin) {
        char[] binString = bin.toCharArray();

        int starting = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < binString.length; i++) {
            int tempoVal = starting * 2
                    + Character.getNumericValue(binString[i]);
            starting = tempoVal;
        }
        return starting;
    }

    public  int reversedBinary(int val){
        String bin =reversedIntToBinary(val);
        int result = toDecimal(bin);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReverseBinary rvb = new ReverseBinary();

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter A Number: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(rvb.reversedBinary(num));
    }
}
```

it is doing the said task, but upon my submission it is wrong. I wondering why it is considered wrong?  have I missed something crucial?

Comment: Maybe it is just the submission packaging. Too many `public`; the function could be `static`. Especially painful seems to me using a StringBuilder. You could shift a bit with << and >>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Output **one line with one integer**, the number we get by reversing the binary representation of N.
>   (emphasis added)

You're outputting *two* lines, `Enter A Number:` and the integer. The text `Enter A Number:\n11\n` is not equal to the text `11\n`. If they're using an automated system to check the programs, it could be failing your submission for that reason.

(I haven't checked your code other than that, so there may be other issues as well -- but that one stands out immediately.)

Comment: What is an alternative I should  do?

Comment: If that's really the problem, the solution is easy: just delete the line `System.out.println("Enter A Number: ");` so that your output obeys the spec they've put out.

Comment: I totally forgot that println adds the `\n` to my formatting thanks!  I thought there was something wrong with my algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If you know the max size of the binary number (4 bits in your example) and it is 8 bits or less, then the fastest way to perform the reversal is with a lookup table using the current binary value as the index.
For example,

```
// indices 0 - 3 of the lookup table.
byte[] lookUpTable =
{
  0b0000, 0b1000, 0b0100, 0b1100
}

// assuming a valid index.
byte reversed = lookUpTable[valueToReverse];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = Integer.reverse( value );
while((result & 1) == 0 && result != 0)
    result >>= 1;
```

**edit** added a bit positioning correction using AND and SHIFT

> public static int reverse(int i)
>
> ```
> Returns the value obtained by reversing the order of the bits in the two's complement binary representation of the specified int value.
>
> Returns:
>     the value obtained by reversing order of the bits in the specified int value.
> Since:
>     1.5
> ```

Comment: Integer.reverse(13) returns -1342177280 not 11, i.e. it is reversing all 32 bits, not just the bits required to make the number.

Comment: @DaveJohnston - Good catch, a simple bit shift to remove the "padding" zeros works.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution: https://github.com/nzpetter/reversebinary

When solving Spotify puzzles I learned one thing. Don't try to invent the wheel. Someone probably has already created methods that you need.

```
public static int reversebinary(int s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(Integer.toBinaryString(s)).reverse().toString(), 2);
}
```